# Change font color in batch file based on a condition

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am looking for a command in batch script that can change the font color based on a result. its like this:
The batch script is used to check a date condition & if it succeeds, copy the files from 1 folder to another. If not it says "0 files copied. File not found".

My requirement is that this "0 files copied. File not found" message alone should come out in red color so that it is easy to catch it.

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: no `cmd` native way. You can [find some useful answers on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+color+line)

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, there are [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+color+line) to do it. My personal favorite:

```
set "write=powershell write-host -foreground"
%write% red this failed
%write% green success
```

you can get valid colors with `powershell help write-host` (or you can use numbers like `color /?` for example `%write% 13 magenta`)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Just a question: "0 files copied. File not found" this is system generated message when the date condition isnt satisfied. Your suggested method will work for that as well?

Comment: obviously not. As soon as `cmd` gets contrlol again, the color is lost. You'd have to write your own STDOUT/STDERR parser (`command >stdout.txt. 2>stderr.txt` and process the textfileson your own (reading the lines and color-print them separately)). What about `if %errorlevel%==1 %write% red CustomFailureMessage`?

Comment: Thanks. I am interested in if %errorlevel%==1 %write% red CustomFailureMessage this approach. Something like if %errorlevel% neq  0 then color message. I am not much into powershell. Is it possible for you to lend some help in using this method as part of my batch file?

Comment: `if %errorlevel% neq 0 %write% red something failed`. No `then` in batch. No need to mess with powershell, as you are only using one single command from it (and already "translated" it to batch as `%write%`). Just use `%write%` like a batch command.

Comment: I tried this. 'red' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Think i am missing something.

Comment: the definition of `%write%`? (first line in my answer code)

Comment: Included that now.. Got this error msg to appear in red now. Thanks !

Comment: But am getting a few red colored lines at the top now when i run the batch file. It says something like "cannot bind parameter 'Foregroundcolor' and something else......... any idea?

Comment: Missing space between `%write%` and `<color>`? or between `<color>` and `<text>`?

Comment: I checked and there are spaces. Anything else?

Comment: hard to say without seeing the exact errormessage (or your exact code). I can't reproduce your finding. Maybe you should ask a new question about it (with `cmd`, `batch-file` and `powershell` tags).

Comment: Great Answer **I used it in this way**  `if %errorlevel% EQU 0  ( %write% green Done!  ) else (  %write% red  Failed  )`

Answer (score 0):

Just before displaying the '0 files copied' message, put this command:

color 04

I assume you'll want to return the color of the screen to the default afterwards. You'll probably have a pause at the end of the batch file. After the pause, put:

color

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. The thing is that I dont know when this msg will get displayed as it depends ont eh condition. This system msg gets displayed only when the condition fails. How can I give it now in the code?

Comment: I thought you were checking the condition yourself - if not, this approach won't work. Have you considered checking the condition and setting the color if it fails, rather than leaving the check as part of the overall command?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I did think on that angle but I was finding it to difficult to acheive this. My date condition check is something like this: get the last modified timestamp of a file & compare the month in it with the current month. If it evaluates to YES, then copy the file else the error message gets thrown. This error msg should come in RED color. Any help?